# Counting subset membership co-occurrences and group alphabet length

Tags: r, traminer

Is there a way in R to count patterns of state co-occurrences in sequences, i.e., to work on groups where element order is not necessarily important? The purpose would be to find out how common are the occurrences of the larger sub-groups within even longer groups.

For example, the input data set would be something like this ('real' data sequences would be  up to ~10 columns wide and 1000s rows deep) ...

```
a,b,c,d
b,c,d,a
c,d,b,a
a,b,c,d,e
b,c,d,a,e
a,b,c
...
```

and the result would perhaps show...

```
abcd, abcd*
```

as a set or class, with a count to indicate number of occurrences, with e.g. * indicating a subset or 'membership elsewhere' category and score based on `length()`.

The results would also show...

```
abcde
```

as a different and slightly rarer set or class, with a higher score reflecting longer `length()`.

And finally ...

```
abc*
```

would have a higher count score, but lower `length()` score.

Something like Traminer that works on unordered (disordered?) groups would be excellent. I note there may be issues with computational load, but I'll consider that (i.e. some sort of triviality threshold) if I need to cut my teeth writing a program.

Comment: I should add that the global alphabet has around 20 characters or factors, and there may be duplicates in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that sorts alphabetically the elements in each sequence, then extracts the successive distinct states of the sorted sequences.

```
dssort <- function(seqdata){
  ssort <- t(apply(seqdata, MARGIN=1, sort))
  ssort.seq <- seqdef(ssort, states=alphabet(seqdata), labels=stlab(seqdata))
  sdss  <- seqdef(seqdss(ssort.seq), missing="%")
  sdss
}
```

Using the outcome of this function you can get the frequencies of the different sets of elements that form the sequences. For example, with

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
shortlab <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[,17:86], states=shortlab)

set <- dssort(mvad.seq)

seqtab(set, tlim=1:3)
```

you get

```
               Freq Percent
EM/1-FE/1        94      13
EM/1-TR/1        84      12
EM/1-JL/1-TR/1   57       8
```

So you know that 94 sequences contain elements `FE` and `EM` and only those two, 84 have `EM` and `TR` and no other state, and 57 have  `EM`, `JL` and `TR`.

You can also plot the frequent sets with `seqfplot(set)`.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but hope it helps.

====

Here is how you can get rid of the useless "/1"

```
tf <- seqtab(set, tlim=1:3, format="STS")
t <- attr(tf,"freq")
rownames(t) <- gsub("-\\*","",rownames(t))
t
```

that gives

```
            Freq   Percent
EM-FE         94 13.202247
EM-TR         84 11.797753
EM-JL-TR      57  8.005618
```

Comment: thanks very much. The function works just fine  though if I change the line 'ssort <- apply(seqdata, MARGIN=2, sort)' to 'ssort <- t(apply(seqdata, MARGIN=1, sort))' to make it work with rows rather than columns. The transpose seems to be needed due to a quirk of the 'apply' function. I would welcome any suggestions to help with ragged rows, to cosmetically suppress '/1-I/1' output effects.

Comment: Should I post my full solution, or would you like to modify yours? I feel you are (much) better qualified to clarify things, but I don't mind having a go......

Comment: @BigOldDave I fixed the error in my code and proposed a way to get rid of the useless "\1".

Comment: Great! I also include`rownames(t) <- gsub("-"," ",rownames(t))` to turn `-I-J-R` into `I J R`. The leading hyphen appears to be due to unequal (ragged) row length.